# Jquery Validation (first character cannot be 0 or symbols)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using Jquery Validation.

Currently, I have a textfield. How can I prompt an alert when user type in 0 or any other symbols as the first character in the field?

```
 $.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function(value, element, regexp) {
        var re = new RegExp(regexp);
        return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
    },
    "Please check your input."
 );
 $("#Textbox").rules("add", { regex: "^[a-zA-Z'.\\s]{1,40}$" })
```

Comment: `0 or any other symbol` = `any symbol`, no? Please be more specific, I'm not sure you really want to alert a user each time he starts typing.

Comment: i dont want to allow user to type in 0 as the first character in the textfield. if user type in 0 as the first character show an alert box.

Comment: alternatively, is there another simple method to check if the first character is 0 for a input textfield?

Comment: I just don't understand this, sorry. The regex you have here does not (or at least should not) allow to use any digits at all in the 'Textbox' field. Are you sure you've quoted it correctly?

Comment: i wasn't sure whether the regex is correct. I am here to clarify to make sure that the user is not allowed to type in 0 as the first character. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at the regex, if all you want is to prevent the first character from being a zero and nothing else, it should be

```
$("#Textbox").rules("add", { regex: "^[^0]$" })
```

To exclude symbols as well you can either add them to the list of prohibited characters

```
$("#Textbox").rules("add", { regex: "^[^0$-/:-?{-~!"^_`\[\]]$" })
```

or specify the characters which are allowed. In this case, lower and uppercase letters, the numbers 1-9, an apostrophe, period or a space

```
$("#Textbox").rules("add", { regex: "^[a-zA-Z1-9'.\s]" })
```